# How to find this filling colourful blanks by applying excel formulas with given data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PzGK.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vU9Y.jpg)   [text](https://stackoverflow.com)
Explain anyone please how to fill by using excel formulas as system no. are multiple and  codes are different with same system no.
[text]([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTfNW.jpg))

Comment: Looks like you need `SUMIFS()`